# Unable to locate the element while using selenium-webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am very much new to selenium WebDriver and I am trying to automate a page which has a button named "Delete Log File". Using FireBug I got to know that, the HTML is described as

and also the css selector is defined as "#DeleteLogButton" using firepath

hence I used 
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#DeleteLogButton").click() in webdriver to click on that button but its now working and also, I tried,

browser.find_element_by_id("DeleteLogButton").click() to click on that button. Even this did not find the solution for my problem...

Please help me out in resolving the issue.

Comment: can you drop your html ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times im using By.xpath and it works specially if you use contains in your xpath. For example : //*[contains(text(),'ABC')]

This will look for all the elements that contains string 'ABC'

In your case you can replace ABC with Delete Log File

Answer (score 0):

try to find it `by name` like :

```
browser.find_element_by_name("Delete Log File").click();
```